# Chrome headless ignores system proxy

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, proxy, google-chrome-headless

Edit: Here's the a youtube video demonstrating the problem:

https://youtu.be/MIZjHKCVr1s

I am running selenium with chrome using the --headless flag but apparently it seems that using --headless ignores system proxy. I had tested this on mac before where it didn't bypass proxy but on windows 10 VM on my mac it seems to bypass the proxy.

code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)

driver.get('https://wtfismyip.com')
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
```

If i don't use the head less flag.
It show the system proxy's IP but if use it it shows my real IP.

Answer (score 5):

There could be a number of reasons for this:
If I had to guess it is Ip leakage.  Low quality proxies do not mask your ip's on various websites.  A good website to test Ip leakage is whoer.net.  Ip address is only one factor, you must also consider browser fingerprinting and user agent spoofing.  Ideally you want whoer.net to have 100% anonymity rating.

Also, ensure you have the latest Chrome and Firefox installed.

I have tested your code and it works.  Perhaps providing your full code with public proxies may help others replicate your job exactly as you see it.  I can only guess how you are using proxies and so my code might differ.  I am also using windows

As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you have provided so I am assuimg that your ip is leaking through another means.  Look into browser fingerprinting and disable webrtc and look closely at whoer.net.

Lastly, Chrome and Firefox have headless support now in the beta editions.  I believe this has always been the case for Linux.  Mac I am not sure on this.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use headless browser try phantom Js.  Though that is being replaced by what I have mentioned above.  I believe there are alternative methods for headless browsing without having to install newer versions of Chrome and Firefox though I do not know how.

EDIT:
Here is an example of how you could use a proxy with Chrome driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:2323" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

I tried this in Selenium and as far as I can tell it worked.

Here's a list of public proxies.  https://free-proxy-list.net/ .  Please note that quite a few of them do not work so I had to scroll through 3 until they work.  I don't think it's necessary to change your network settings for proxies just use the code above.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I am adding the ip from NetworkSettings>Proxy

While I admit it's a low quality free proxy, this error only happens when I use the '--headless' flag. For everything else the proxy works, even running chrome itself but without the '--headless' flag. I tried using '--proxy-server="my proxy"' as specified on their site but it just crashes when I do that.

Comment: @rjpj1998 Please see my edited post. Hope that helps with proxy set up. You can use a vpn but that can be quite slow.  A good proxy can sometimes be all you need.  If you are going to use proxies for important jobs, I suggest buying proxies from a reliable source.  Luminati is a good one but pretty expensive.  You'd have to talk to them about prepaid .  I believe they are socks 5 I believe.  Socks 5 is most secure proxy.  Use whoer.net to test for leakage!

Comment: @rjpj1998 I see.  Maybe an alternative method for creating a headless browser might work.  Can this issue be replicated on another computer?  It might be a mac specific issue and I can't seem to replicate it with windows.  It could also be a python installation issue but maybe not.  Sometimes issues pop up if you are using anaconda v python etc,, Sorry I can't be of more help as the above worked for me. I hope you find a solution.

Comment: I get this problem when running on windows in a VM on my mac. The program works well on my ubuntu VPS and my mac but on my windows VM, It messes up. I even tried using proxy for both mac and windows but still for some god forsaken reason it doesn't use any proxy. If i used --proxy-server flag it just crashes at chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: Can you run the above program using the "--headless" flag as well?

Comment: @rjpj1998 A vps you say.  I am just using windows.  Hmm Oh I didn't test the ip headless.  How are you able to read what your ip is if it's headless?  You could print the element of ip on the webpage or I assume you can view it headless.,  Though that would just be removing the headless tag wouldn't it?.  Is it strictly related to a virtual machine of windows and Ubuntu and mac works?  IF that's the case, it's narrowed down a lot but there are so many different reasons it could be happening,  I am sure you'll work it out eventually.

Comment: @rjpj1998 Perhaps sending an image of the error or a video or whatever can not only help others see what you see but help yourself identify what the causal issue is likely to be.

Comment: Ok I will record and upload to youtube now.